# Excel, "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=if(C15=0,(B14+(VLOOKUP(C16,,'Locks and Readers per day'!D:E, 2, false))),(B15+(VLOOKUP(C16,'Locks and Readers per day'!D:E, 2,FALSE))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an extra `,` in the first vlookup.

Comment: BTW it can be simplified to: `=IF(C15=0,B14,B15) +VLOOKUP(C16,'Locks and Readers per day'!D:E, 2, FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a comma to much :

```
=if(C15=0,(B14+(VLOOKUP(C16,'Locks and Readers per day'!D:E, 2, false))),(B15+(VLOOKUP(C16,'Locks and Readers per day'!D:E, 2,FALSE))))
```